# How do I select the input before and after a comma in VBS?

Tags: string, variables, vbscript

I am programming something to do my math for me and instead of making more than one input box for one coordinate point like so:

```
Option Explicit
Dim X,Y
X=InputBox("Enter X")
Y=InputBox("Enter Y")
```

I would like to know how to set Y and X from typing in "(X,Y)" instead of them separately,
and if possible set Y1, Y2, X1, and X2 with "(X1,Y1) (X2,Y2)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get parts from a string, you can use

Split:

```
>> s = "4,5"
>> a = Split(s, ",")
>> m = CLng(a(0))
>> n = CLng(a(1))
>> WScript.Echo m, n, m + n
>>
4 5 9
```

a regular expression

```
>> s = "4,5"
>> Set r = New RegExp
>> r.Pattern = "\d+"
>> r.Global = True
>> Set ms = r.Execute(s)
>> m = CLng(ms(0))
>> n = CLng(ms(1))
>> WScript.Echo m, n, m + n
>>
4 5 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to achieve in the end you could also use the [`Execute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03t418d2%28v=vs.84%29) statement:

```
expr = InputBox("Enter mathematical expression:")
Execute "result = " & expr
WScript.Echo expr & " = " & result
```

As Ekkehard.Horner pointed out in the comments, you could also use [`Eval`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z5x4094%28v=vs.84%29), which has the additional advantage that you don't have to include the assignment in the evaluated string:

```
expr = InputBox("Enter mathematical expression:")
result = Eval(expr)
WScript.Echo expr & " = " & result
```

Note that both of these are more of a quick'n'dirty approach and should *not* be used in production environments unless you add some serious input validation.

Comment: Good idea for applications like a calculator, but I'd prefer Eval  - result = Eval(expr) - instead of Execute.